# Can't get oauth working on MacOS Ventura with PHP 8.2.2

Tags: php, macos, oauth

My macbook with MacOS Ventura (13.2) just upgraded to PHP 8.2.2 trough Brew but now i'm having problems because php ext-oauth is not active.

When I run composer install in my (Symfony) project I get this message:

```
Problem 1

- Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-oauth * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's oauth extension.


To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

- /usr/local/etc/php/8.2/php.ini

- /usr/local/etc/php/8.2/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini

You can also run php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I've googled and tried:

- adding it to the current php.ini file
- `sudo pecl install oauth`
  *(returns the message "pecl/oauth is already installed and is the same
  as the released version 2.0.7")*
- I've even copied the previous oauth.so file to the current php directory.
- `php -m` doesn't return the oauth extension in the list

Any ideas, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've got running again by do these steps:

- open terminal
- `sudo pecl uninstall oauth`
- `sudo pecl install oauth`